# cakephp offline tasks

Tags: cakephp-2.0

I have a site which runs a quite intensive job from the admin panel. 
I would somehow like to run it without interfering with the output it produce.

To make it more clear. On submitting a form I must unzip a big zip file, and for every image I fin, I must insert it to my database. This process takes more than 3-4 minutes. So I would like to put the job running and output that the job is being processed. 
I don't know if I can notify user then (maybe through an ajax call) but I don't mind that.

Is it possible?

thanks

Answer (score 0):

It depends on what you want the user to do while you're processing the data.

Do you want him to wait? Then use a AJAX call and display a progress bar (or whatever you like) until the task is complete. When the task is complete, inform the user (via ajax again) and proceed with  (whatever) functionality you've got in store.

If you want the file to be processed while the user is doing something else, you can call (CakePHP) [ShellTask](http://book.cakephp.org/2.0/en/console-and-shells.html#shell-tasks) in the background and let it do its' magic. If you want for the User to be able to view what the status of a import is, you can create a imports table, that stores information about all imports. By using a "status" field, the user can know that, for e.g. the task is still running.
When the shell task completes you can change the "status" of the import and do what ever. This needs to be done in the task itself, but it wouldn't be a problem because you can use models in Shell Tasks - the same way you can [use models in Shells](http://book.cakephp.org/2.0/en/console-and-shells.html#using-models-in-your-shells).

Hope this helps, comment if you need any further clarification.